# Selecting multiple columns

Tags: sql, psql

I have these tables:

- machine
- machine_component_lookup
- component

machine_component_lookup table has records that give keys to component table records given a primary key of machine table. I want to list columns from component and machine table

```
select port,
       portrole,
       machine.machine_key 
  from component a 
 where a.component_key in (select b.component_key 
                             from machine_component_lookup b 
                             join machine c 
                               on b.machine_key =c.machine_key );
```

I get error as   missing FROM-clause entry for table , what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

DB engine doesn't see `machine` table in main query. If you want to display `machine_key` from the table try below code please.

```
select a.port,
       a.portrole,
       c.machine_key 
  from component a 
  join machine_component_lookup b on  a.component_key = b.component_key 
  join machine c on b.machine_key =c.machine_key ;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
select a.port,
       a.portrole,
       c.machine_key 
  from component a INNER JOIN
  machine_component_lookup b ON a.component_key = b.component_key INNER JOIN
  machine c  on b.machine_key =c.machine_key
```

Answer (score 0):

i think is:

```
select port, portrole, a.component_key as machine_key from component a 
where a.component_key in (select b.component_key from machine_component_lookup b join machine c on b.machine_key =c.machine_key );
```